# Where is the "iOS Would Like Access to Twitter Accounts" alert?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, settings, uialertview

When you first ever open a new app, whether you're a developer making one, or you have just downloaded from the app store, if **Twitter** access is needed, it will ask for it.

I can only get this `AlertView` to show once, per device. No matter what I do, I can't get it back, deleting the app + data, re-building it from Xcode, revoking access to Twitter accounts on the device itself...

None of these work.

I can detect in the code whether on not I have access to Twitter, but it was more of a UI problem I was having when it first appeared. So I really need to see it again.

If anyone could help that'd be great!

Comment: The OS only shows it once per application; to change the setting later requires going into the Settings app. There isn't a way to have it show again.

Comment: This is utterly devastating to hear, but thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invoke the dialog again, change app id temporarily. Since app id uniquely identifies an app, it'll be like a new app.

Comment: Temporarily? So you need to change it again and then the dialog pops up again?

Comment: Temporarily as in you'll need to revert to whatever you have in iTunes connect before publishing. So change app id > test workflow > revert changes when done testing.